# Xamarin Android, Xamarin-Cropper and SDK 28

Tags: android, xamarin.android

My stack is Xamarin Android and VS 2017.

I'm using this package for image cropping - https://github.com/mikescandy/Xamarin-Cropper. It is a binding library for https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper. When I changed my target Android version to Android 9.0 (API Level 28) I experience following exception:

Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed

I believe it is related to Android 28 SDK. I found a fix for that in a native library:

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/commit/2e7e1bf36261aea2dd2400a75041c1ad7118fff1

I tried to create a Xamarin.Android binding library myself, using .aar file downloaded from:

https://bintray.com/arthurhub/maven/Android-Image-Cropper/2.8.0#files/com%2Ftheartofdev%2Fedmodo%2Fandroid-image-cropper%2F2.8.0

but when I use it in my project (I use cropper as a View) it says:

The type or namespace name 'CropImageView' could not be found

Does anyone have more luck using this library for Android 28 SDK?

Comment: Sorry,  I couldn't reproduce this question.Could you please share the steps  of reproducing this question?

Comment: Hi Jessie! Is there any way I can share my test project with you?

Comment: Yes, you can upload your project here: https://github.com/

Comment: HI Jessie! I hope you are still willing to help. Thanks in advance! You can found my project here: https://github.com/kkazmierczak/XamarinAndroidImageCropper. What I want to do is simply use never version of cropper aar file (2.8.0), which I hope has Invalid Region.Op issue fixed. I replaced the aar file in sample project, but then sample app is not working anymore. To be honest I have no idea why. Maybe you could give me some hint how I can fix ir. Thank you very much in advance!